# DHCP fixed-address for linux bridge

Tags: linux, dhcp, bridge

I'm trying to setup a bridge port (eth0, eth1) on Ubuntu Linux 16.04. LTS

My configuration in /etc/network/interfaces looks like this:

```
# Loopback interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# set interfaces manually to avoid conflicts
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual

# Bridge interface
# bring up interface with DHCP and set permanent MAC address
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0 eth1
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_hw aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:fc
```

My eth0 has MAC aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:fa

My eth1 has MAC aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:fb

I want to give DHCP fixed-address to the br0 interface, so the definition in dhcpd.conf file (ISC DHCP) looks like this:

```
host myHost {
     hardware ethernet aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:fc;
     fixed-address 192.168.x.y;
     ddns-hostname myhost;
 }
```

I expected that the IP address of myHost will be assigned to the br0, but always the MAC address of eth0 is sent to the DHCP server and the br0 get assigned an IP from another pool (temporary clients). The dhcpd.leases file then shows the MAC from eth0.

Bridging itself works like a charm, but since I always want the same address on br0 regardless if physically eth0 or eth1 is connected, I need a solution here.
(When plugging in eth1, MAC from eth1 is sent to DHCP server)

Any ideas?

Regards
Olaf

P.S.: Static IP address is not an option ...